# Widgets not displaying since 4.3

Tags: widgets

I had some basic widgets registered and assigned to sidebars which were working prior to upgrading to WordPress 4.3.

```
class Footer_Contact_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::WP_Widget('contact_details','Contact Details','description=Contact Details for Footer');
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        // outputs the options form on admin
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        // processes widget options to be saved
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo "Output stuff";
    }
}
```

These stopped working presumably in part due to the [deprecated PHP4-style constructors](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/02/deprecating-php4-style-constructors-in-wordpress-4-3/). So I updated my constructor call accordingly:

```
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('contact_details','Contact Details','description=Contact Details for Footer');
    }
```

Now the constructor runs correctly but my `widget()` method still doesn't.

In digging down to the parent `WP_Widget` class defined in `wp-includes/widgets.php` it appears the `WP_Widget::display_callback()` method is bailing out because my widgets don't have "settings":

```
public function display_callback( $args, $widget_args = 1 ) {
    if ( is_numeric( $widget_args ) ) {
            $widget_args = array( 'number' => $widget_args );
    }

    $widget_args = wp_parse_args( $widget_args, array( 'number' => -1 ) );

    $this->_set( $widget_args['number'] );
    $instances = $this->get_settings();

    if ( isset( $instances[ $this->number ] ) ) {
        # Normally proceeds to call ->widget() but does not evaluate
```

If I have two widgets like this, the value of `$instances` is something like `array(2) { [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL }`. The `NULL` value means `isset( $instances[ $this->number ] )` is false.

But the thing is my widgets don't have settings. I'm a bit lost as to what else might have changed in this version of WordPress.

Comment: Removing my empty `form()` and `update()` methods allowed the widget to function again, although it had to be removed from the sidebar and added again. Not sure why.